# Android: How to create a GridLayout [not GridView] programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I am developing a "match the following" application. The xml used for the application is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lytLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Match the following questions with their answers." />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:columnWidth="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Q1Lyt"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_qn"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Q1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Question1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/A1Lyt"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Answer1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/A1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Answer1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Q2Lyt"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_qn"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Q2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/A2Lyt"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/A2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Answer2" />
        </LinearLayout>
   </GridLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried the following code to create the grid layout. However, for the child linear layouts, I am unable to find a way to programmatically set the android:layout_column and android:layout_row parameters.

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(15);

    LinearLayout lyt1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams prmsLinLyt = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Any pointers?

Comment: I have not been able to dig further information. Hence, I am using a table layout instead.

Comment: I don't undestand why this question has been closed. I think it is an error. It would have helped me if the question was answered.

Comment: var gridLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
gridLayoutParams.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Fill);
gridLayoutParams.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(iRow, 1);
gridLayoutParams.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(iCol, 1); grid.AddView(aView, gridLayoutParams);

Comment: I would also have found this to be a helpful question to have answered

Comment: Same, I would have benefited from an answer.  Is there a way to reopen?

Answer (score 9):

Here is how You can create it programmatically:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(getContext());

// Add Title
GridLayout.Spec titleTxtSpecColumn = GridLayout.spec(2, GridLayout.BASELINE);
GridLayout.Spec titleRowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
TextView titleText = new TextView(getContext());
titleText.setText("Title");

gridLayout.addView(titleText, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(titleRowSpec , titleTxtSpecColumn));
```

For more details see ApiDemos examples.

Comment: All rows / columns are added into the same cell.

Answer (score -3):

You should try this :

```
  gridLayout.setLayoutParams(prmsLinLyt);
```

and if you want to give values...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams prmsLinLyt = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90,100);

where layout_width = 90
and layout_height= 100
```

Comment: Thanks I am aware of that. But, I am unable to find an equivalent for android:layout_column and android:layout_row parameters. Those do not show up in the properties of prmsLinLyt.